# Google Forms addressed only certain people

Tags: google-forms

I would like to create a survey on Google Forms, addressed only and for certain and specific people.

the user must enter the name, surname and other data. if this information does not match those in the database, the user will not be able to continue the survey.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality you seek does not exist. The best you can have is to filter out alien submissions in postprocessing, eg. in your spreadsheet you will have a little database of valid names and you will filter out form submissions against this database so if someone will submit the form and it's not on your list then it will get nullified.